# How can I log user info (like username, firstName etc...)?

Tags: logging, apostrophe-cms

I'm trying to create my logger with winston e I'd like log info about logged user. There is a way to get these info?

thanks
Roberto

Answer (score 2):

If you're in Apostrophe's nunjucks templates you will have access to `data.user`. If you are on the server you often have information about the user in `req.user`